# Broker: find a Page using a specific Component and Component Template

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-delivery, broker, query, brokerquery

I have a use case where I need to find the Page URL from a Page using a certain Component Presentation (given `componentId` and `templateId`).

I am trying to find the Page using `Criteria` but I can't find the right combination.

I tried using `ComponentLink.getLinkAsString` method but that method uses `templateId` parameter as "exclude" instead of "preferred template".

I know the information is there but I can't find a way to it.
I'm trying this:

```
criteriaURL.add(new ItemTypeCriteria(64));
criteriaURL.add(new ItemReferenceCriteria(ComponentId));
criteriaURL.add(new ItemTemplateCriteria(ComponentTemplateId));
```

Even using only `ItemTemplateCriteria` and `ItemTypeCriteria`, I don't get any results.

Comment: It seems that it can't be done using the public API.

Finally I found a solution using Nickoli's answer: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7138/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-the-component-links-for-a-given-component-presentation